# Change variable data within actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've created a button that contains an actionlistener. I declared the variable outside the actionlistener. But I can't change the variable content inside the actionlistener. I always get the error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

How can I solve the problem?

I hope the code section is good enough for you.

I've already tried with:

```
final int player = 1;
```

But I can't change the content with final.

```
public void Game(char[] gamefield) { 
    int player = 1;
    TickTackToeSpieleablauf window = new TickTackToeSpieleablauf();
    btnSpielebrett1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //Field1
           int field = 0;
           boolean geklappt = false;
           geklappt = window.playervsplayer(gamefield, field, player);
           System.out.println(gamefield[0]);
           if (geklappt && player == 1){
               gamefield[field] = 'x';
               player = 2; <----- HERE I GET THE ERROR
           }else if(geklappt && player == 2){
               gamefield[field] = 'o';
           }else if(!geklappt){
                if (gamefield[0] != '1' && gamefield[1] != '2' &&gamefield[2] != '3' && gamefield[3] != '4' &&gamefield[4] != '5' && gamefield[5] != '6' &&gamefield[6] != '7' && gamefield[7] != '8' &&gamefield[8] != '9'){
                    //Gamefield full, array clear;
                        gamefield[0] = '1';
                        gamefield[1] = '2';
                        gamefield[2] = '3';
                        gamefield[3] = '4';
                        gamefield[4] = '5';
                        gamefield[5] = '6';
                        gamefield[6] = '7';
                        gamefield[7] = '8';
                        gamefield[8] = '9';
                }
           }else{
               System.out.println("Feld bereits belegt.");
           }
}
```

Comment: Create a class implementing `ActionListener` that will have access to your instance or have your current class implement `ActionListener`. Using an inner class come with the restriction that every variables are "final" even if you don't defined them as one, they are effectively final (or it doesn't compile)

Comment: PS : what is the point of `player` in this since you are not using it at all. The variable is limited to the method scope, it is not part of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu can provide a wrapper class for your `player` value, say:

```
class Player {
    int value = 1;
}
```

And use the reference to this class instead of the primitive type:

```
final Player player = new Player();

...

if (geklappt && player.value == 1){
      gamefield[field] = 'x';
      player.value = 2;
}
```